# How to get new URL parameters in a Webview?

Tags: android, android-webview, inappbrowser

I would like to ask how to implement this, i have an application where in if i click a certain button it will access a webview in-app browser, the problem is that from the webview there is a button that, when clicked will redirect into a new page. the question is how am i able to get the URL of that new page? for example. the original URL is **www.abc.com/home** and when I clicked the button on the web page it will go to another page **www.abc.com/page2**. how to get the **www.abc.com/page2**. I am able to get **www.abc.com/home** easily using `onPageFinished`. but cant gets the next page. note that I clicked the button on the webpage itself. i used already the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` but it doesn't work. any ideas? a good example will do. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Out :

```
WebView webview = new WebView(context);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                Log.d("WebView", "your current url when webpage loading.." + url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.d("WebView", "your current url when webpage loading.. finish" + url);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                System.out.println("when you click on any interlink on webview that time you got url :-" + url);
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        });
```

Comment: how to do this if im using webChromeClient?

Comment: Use webviewclient . Besides you can use webChromeClient as you need.

Comment: the problem is that i can only use onProgressChange using webChromeClient, because it display/ get the current/changed URL the webapp by the way is a SPA (single page application) anywork around? thank you!

Comment: try onPageFinished .